# How to fix 'Segmentation fault' error in c++

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn how to use the gdb debugger to fix this sample code. When stepping through the debugger, I can see that the line 'mylist[i]->val = i;' is throwing the segmentation fault.

I think I understand what a segmentation fault is, but I don't understand how this line could be causing it. Do I need to allocate memory for the mylist vector? How would I do that? I thought that the vector was already initialized and ready in main(), but I'm not really sure.

I have tried using 'new' for each node in the mylist vector but that gave me  a compile error.

```
node* mylist[i] = new node; //what I tried
mylist[i]->val = i; 
mylist[i]->next = NULL;   

//error message
error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
node* mylist[i] = new node;
```

My code

```
class node
{
public:
    int val;
    node* next;
};

void create_LL(vector<node*>& mylist, int node_num)
{
    mylist.assign(node_num, NULL);

//create a set of nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < node_num; i++)
    {
        mylist[i]->val = i; //error happens here
        mylist[i]->next = NULL;
    }

... (relevant section of main() below)

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const int NODE_NUM = 3;
    vector<node*> mylist;
    create_LL(mylist, NODE_NUM);
```

The actual error shown is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

When I print mylist right before the error line it shows

```
$1 = std::vector of length 3, capacity 3 = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0}
```

I am still learning c++ so I might be missing something really basic.
I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the nodes. You're just adding a bunch of null pointers to your vector. If you have an issue allocating the memory it would be best to post that attempt with the full error message. It's also unclear what you're attempting to do. a vector of linked list nodes is kinda odd.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how to allocate memory for the nodes. I tried adding this "node* mylist[i] = new node;" above the error line but I got the array must be initialized error

Comment: Where are you populating the vector?

Comment: The vector is never populated, it is initialized in main() and then immediately called in create_LL(). It is supposed to just contain 3 nodes with keys assigned to i (0, 1, 2)

Comment: Initialize the vector as `vector<node*> mylist(NODE_NUM, new node())`

Comment: @yabhishek, That's no good because each element would be a copy of the same pointer (hence sharing one node across all elements).

Comment: @chris That's right, realized that now. Vector initializers are good for non-referenced object types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, it's better if you hide variables inside a `class`. If you're not going to, the convention is to use a `struct`. It's also good practice to provide some constructor in that case, and maybe with default values:

```
class node
{
    int val;
    node* next;
public:
    node(int v= 0, node* n= nullptr) : val(v), next(n) {}
};
```

Note the use of `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Using the latter is a bad practice in c++.

The problem is that you can't use positions on a `std::vector` if they have not been allocated. When you do `mylist[i]->val = i;` you're in the lands of undefined behaviour.

You need first to `push_back()` or `emplace_back()` into a `std::vector`. So it's `size()` grows as it puts your data at the end (the `back`) of the `vector`. You could also use other methods, like `reserve()`. While `push_back()` pushes `node*` elements on your list, `emplace_back()` would construct them in place with no copy (no difference with raw pointers, but you can use a `vector<node>` instead of `vector<node*>` which is more straightforward.

```
// create a set of nodes
void create_LL(vector<node>& mylist, int node_num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < node_num; i++) {
        mylist.emplace_back(i, nullptr); // calls node::node(i, nullptr) and inserts it at the end of the vector
    }
```

or

```
// create a set of nodes
void create_LL(vector<node*>& mylist, int node_num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < node_num; i++) {
        mylist.emplace_back(new node(i, nullptr));
    }
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you wrote some of the explanation in the body of your answer, and not just as comments in the code.  It kind of looks like a code-only answer as is.  It should at least have an introductory statement saying what the problem was and how your solution fixes the problem.